# Preferred DNS Server Settings on a Domain using Multiple DNS Servers?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-domain

I manage a small business network with two separate physical locations, these locations are connected using a pair of VPN Routers(192.168.1.1, and 192.168.128.1).
The primary location uses a DNS Server with Active directory, The network and routers used this as there preferred DNS Server.
I recently added a Secondary DNS Server in the other location, replicating the Active Directory from the Primary DNS Server. The installation went smoothly without any issues.
The Primary Server always used it's own IP Address as it's preferred DNS Server, but with the addition of the Secondary Server, should I now change the preferred DNS settings on the Primary DNS Server, and should I Use the Primary DNS Server IP as the preferred DNS Server on the Secondary Server, or have it use it's own IP as it's preferred Server?

Comment: Haven't covered this topic in a long time however when I did pass my MCP's the recommended method was to have the DNS server to use itself as preferred and the secondary as the secondary DNS server on the network, then the same for the secondary server to use itself and the other server as the secondary.

Comment: @CharlesH, There seems to be two schools of thought on this, the first being your suggestion, and the other being the opposite, that the primary server use the secondary as it's 1st, and it's own 2nd, and the Secondary Server use the Primary 1st, and it's own 2nd?

Comment: I would say using itself as the primary is more effective for local changes as it will be finding these new records prior to replication. For example your machine name changes your local DNS will know about it and due to it looking at itself it will 'see' the change before the secondary which will have the older record until replication is complete. It could be (along with a lot of replication/Microsoft feature) something that is more important in a bigger environment.

Comment: Thank You for your response, Our Network currently has about 40-45 users, and is growing. I'm going to be making some Server upgrades soon, and when I do I'll use your suggestion to use The Servers IP as it's 1st preferred DNS Server.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to follow the best practice that's detailed here: https://serverfault.com/questions/394804/what-should-the-order-of-dns-servers-be-for-an-ad-domain-controller-and-why/394805#394805

**TLDR**

1. **Primary DNS**:   *The IP of the **other** D.C.*
2. **Secondary DNS**: 127.0.0.1